# Where do I find good material on the Observer design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Where to find good material to study observer pattern? I need some examples, of code and also pictures of modelled situations

Comment: [This post](http://ayp-sd.blogspot.com/2013/01/observer-design-pattern-in-java.html) might be helpful for you. It doesn't describe Observer design pattern in general, but it shows how to implement it efficiently using modern Java features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the chapter on the Observer pattern from the **Design Patterns in Java** book can be viewed on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=S5ebGvuLJqQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=design+patterns+in+java&ei=QOaYS4GnDY78zQTwp9WhCg&cd=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Same thing for [Head First Design pattern](http://books.google.com/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=head+first+design+patterns&ei=yuaYS9SxBKCSyQSG1bHGCg&cd=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false)s, by the way.

[alt text http://bks6.books.google.com/books?id=S5ebGvuLJqQC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&sig=ACfU3U3OFvA14Y4IKb9iZ-eH664YW15Fbg](http://bks6.books.google.com/books?id=S5ebGvuLJqQC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&sig=ACfU3U3OFvA14Y4IKb9iZ-eH664YW15Fbg) 
[alt text http://bks1.books.google.com/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&sig=ACfU3U1t6E1H5cFgQvMyhE8hkYJk-Rt0Lg](http://bks1.books.google.com/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&sig=ACfU3U1t6E1H5cFgQvMyhE8hkYJk-Rt0Lg)

Answer (score 6):

Head first design patterns is the book for you.
There are loads of pictures in this book.
[image]
<sub>(source: [headfirstlabs.com](http://headfirstlabs.com/Images/hfdp_cover.gif))</sub>

[Here is the code for observer pattern and other patterns (JAVA).](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/)

Comment: good stuff, I've found example of what the book can offer. Quite funny is first picture with a man drinking coffee:D
 see the pdf
http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For starters: [Observer on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). It includes examples in Java, Python and C++, and lots of links.

Here is a [C# example & UML diagram](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx).

Comment: it seems good although have aversion to wikipedia. I am from czech republic and czech wikipedia does not have a lot of informations on specialised problems.

Comment: @joseph change to the english version; update the url with en in stead of your country code. But I agree, the default non-english page sucks big time.

Comment: @joseph this is the English version. It has very good information about most known design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [nice dzone article about the observer pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered). You may also like [Non-software examples of Software Design Patterns](http://www.cours.polymtl.ca/inf3700/divers/nonSoftwareExample/patexamples.html).